# Mod Player for iphone

Tags: iphone

I'm wondering if anyone has knowledge of any kind of modplayer library for iphone? I've searched, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MikMod](http://www.algonet.se/~afb/mikmod/macosx-player.zip) for the mac uses CoreAudio, so it might "just work" on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully implemented a mod/s3m player on the iPhone using [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW5).

Answer (score 0):

I have a chiptune player nearly finished : it's based on modplug for the module part.
basically it is as simple as recompiling the lib (modplug) and interface it with an audio buffer queue, as stated by Manuel.
here's a quick video of my stuff :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGJ560-qAio

do not hesitate to send an email if you need some help

Answer (score 0):

For a non-app version, it may be worth checking out Matt Westcott's JSModPlayer:
http://matt.west.co.tt/music/jsmodplayer/

It is Javascript and heavily under development, already there is a fork of it on GitHub. It does work though, but is a bit of a CPU hog!